# $\int_{0}^\infty e^{-xu}\sin x \, dx$: Where is my mistake?

Tags: calculus, integration

Below find a a scan of a page out of Buck's *Advanced Calculus*. Right below the line marked (6-33), he seems to claim that $\int_{0}^\infty e^{-xu}\sin x \,dx = \frac{1}{1+u^2}$ (for $u>0$). I keep getting $\frac{u^2}{1+u^2}$, and I'm wondering if I'm making a mistake, or if there's a typo.

$$\int_{0}^\infty e^{-xu}\sin x \, dx = \int_{0}^\infty e^{-xu} d(-\cos x)=-\cos x e^{-xu}]_{0}^{\infty}-\int_{0}^\infty(-\cos x)d(e^{-xu})$$ $$=1 + \frac{-1}{u}\int_{0}^\infty e^{-xu}\cos x \, dx=1 - \frac{1}{u}\int_{0}^\infty e^{-xu}d(\sin x)$$ $$= 1 - \frac{1}{u}\left([e^{-xu}\sin x]_{0}^{\infty} - \int_{0}^\infty \sin x \,d (e^{-xu})\right)= 1 - \frac{1}{u}\left(\frac{1}{u}\int_{0}^\infty e^{-xu}\sin x \, dx\right)$$ so
$$I = 1 - \frac{1}{u^2}I \Rightarrow \frac{u^2 + 1}{u^2}I = 1 \Rightarrow I = \frac{u^2}{u^2+1}.$$

What do you think?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem you made a careless error. What is $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}e^{ux}$?

Answer (score 4):

You wrote 
$$d(e^{-xu})=-\frac{1}{u}e^{-xu}dx$$
which's wrong and you should write
$$d(e^{-xu})=-ue^{-xu}dx$$

Comment: Thank you both! Of course!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Spot on! Short and sweet.